# Git installation for a newer version fails on ./configure

Tags: centos, bash, git, centos6.4

I'm trying to upgrade my Git version to 1.8.3 on my fresh new CentOS 6.4 server(Cloud).

I'm trying these [instructions here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/install/centos/README.md) because I will then install the Gitlab. I have used this document before on my VirtualBox CentOS installation, I had no errors there.

However, this time after I clone the git repo, I can't compile, it fails on this line:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

Here's the error that I get:

```
-bash: ./configure: Permission denied
```

I've updated the permissions, the result didn't change. I have used `sh ./configure` and it did seem to work at first but then it broke down with this error:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... configure: error: in `/tmp/git':  
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.  
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
```

What might be the problem? Some similar issues are told to use `mount` command but I couldn't make anything work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the output of # mount

Comment: Hi, I have kept on searching and came out with this, it worked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1774394/705982 Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to install git-1.8.3. from [IUS Community repo](http://iuscommunity.org/)

```
# yum info git18
Available Packages
Name        : git18
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.8.3.4
Release     : 1.ius.centos6
Size        : 6.7 M
Repo        : ius
Summary     : Fast Version Control System
URL         : http://git-scm.com/
License     : GPLv2
Description : Git is a fast, scalable, distributed revision control system with an
            : unusually rich command set that provides both high-level operations
            : and full access to internals.
            :
            : The git rpm installs the core tools with minimal dependencies.  To
            : install all git packages, including tools for integrating with other
            : SCMs, install the git-all meta-package.
```

Comment: I didn't solve my problem with this solution, however if I knew this method, I'd prefer it. Because the CentOS comes with Git 1.7.1 and Gitlab requires above. Thanks.